# How to animate facial recognition svg UI in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, svg

I am building a facial recognition application flow, on this particular screen, I have an image that's meant to increase incrementally when the facial recognition is satisfied with the current status. My issue is increasing the size of the individual lines. I've been pulling my hair understanding it but it's not working. Here's an image of what I have;

[image]

So I'm trying to make each line grow in size once the application is satisfied with the current status.

Here's the svg code to the image.

```
 <svg width="229" height="229" viewBox="0 0 229 229" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_8741_44866)">
                <path d="M150.824 198.947C197.463 178.881 219.004 124.805 198.938 78.1662C178.871 31.5271 124.795 9.98597 78.1564 30.0526C31.5174 50.1192 9.97621 104.195 30.0429 150.834C50.1095 197.473 104.185 219.014 150.824 198.947Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M103 89.25H102.45C97.8296 89.25 95.5194 89.25 93.7546 90.1492C92.2022 90.9402 90.9402 92.2022 90.1492 93.7546C89.25 95.5194 89.25 97.8296 89.25 102.45V103M103 138.75H102.45C97.8296 138.75 95.5194 138.75 93.7546 137.851C92.2022 137.06 90.9402 135.798 90.1492 134.245C89.25 132.481 89.25 130.17 89.25 125.55V125M138.75 103V102.45C138.75 97.8296 138.75 95.5194 137.851 93.7546C137.06 92.2022 135.798 90.9402 134.245 90.1492C132.481 89.25 130.17 89.25 125.55 89.25H125M138.75 125V125.55C138.75 130.17 138.75 132.481 137.851 134.245C137.06 135.798 135.798 137.06 134.245 137.851C132.481 138.75 130.17 138.75 125.55 138.75H125M101.625 103V107.125M126.375 103V107.125M111.25 115.65C113.45 115.65 115.375 113.725 115.375 111.525V103M122.801 122.8C117.851 127.75 109.876 127.75 104.926 122.8" stroke="#737A91" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <g>
                    <path d="M114.5 0.874023V18.1976" stroke="#25C26E" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                    <path d="M124.569 18.7221L126.369 1.50342" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M134.516 20.2955L138.117 3.35645" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M144.252 22.9174L149.619 6.43286" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M153.675 26.5185L160.72 10.6982" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M162.66 31.0985L171.313 16.0999" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M171.103 36.5876L181.294 22.5679" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M178.935 42.9331L190.524 30.0671" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M186.067 50.0654L198.933 38.4756" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M192.413 57.8967L206.432 47.7053" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M197.901 66.3401L212.9 57.687" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M202.481 75.3253L218.302 68.2805" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M206.083 84.7475L222.567 79.3809" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M208.705 94.4844L225.644 90.8833" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M210.278 104.431L227.497 102.63" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M210.802 114.5H228.126" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M210.278 124.569L227.497 126.37" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M208.705 134.516L225.644 138.117" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M206.083 144.252L222.567 149.619" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M202.481 153.675L218.302 160.72" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M197.901 162.66L212.9 171.313" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M192.413 171.103L206.432 181.295" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M186.067 178.935L198.933 190.524" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M178.935 186.067L190.524 198.933" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M171.103 192.412L181.294 206.432" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M162.66 197.901L171.313 212.9" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M153.675 202.481L160.72 218.302" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M144.252 206.1L149.619 222.567" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M134.516 208.705L138.117 225.644" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M124.569 210.278L126.369 227.497" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M114.5 210.802V228.126" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M102.63 227.497L104.431 210.278" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M90.8833 225.644L94.4844 208.705" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M79.3809 222.567L84.7475 206.1" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M68.2803 218.302L75.3251 202.481" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M57.687 212.9L66.3401 197.901" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M47.7056 206.432L57.8969 192.412" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M38.4756 198.933L50.0654 186.067" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M30.0674 190.524L42.9333 178.935" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M22.5679 181.295L36.5876 171.103" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M16.1001 171.313L31.0987 162.66" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M10.6982 160.72L26.5185 153.675" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M6.43311 149.619L22.9176 144.252" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M3.35645 138.117L20.2955 134.516" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M1.50342 126.37L18.7221 124.569" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M0.874023 114.5H18.1976" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M1.50342 102.63L18.7221 104.431" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M3.35645 90.8833L20.2955 94.4844" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M6.43311 79.3809L22.9176 84.7475" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M10.6982 68.2805L26.5185 75.3253" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M16.1001 57.687L31.0987 66.3401" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M22.5679 47.7053L36.5876 57.8967" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M30.0674 38.4756L42.9333 50.0654" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M38.4756 30.0671L50.0654 42.9331" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M47.7056 22.5679L57.8969 36.5876" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M57.687 16.0999L66.3401 31.0985" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M68.2803 10.6982L75.3251 26.5185" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M79.3809 6.43286L84.7475 22.9174" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M90.8833 3.35645L94.4844 20.2955" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M102.63 1.50342L104.431 18.7221" stroke="#737A91" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_8741_44866">
                    <rect width="229" height="229" fill="white"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the transform property ? Changing the path is gonna be tricky. Maybe there's a way to individually make the path scale up

Comment: @Scaraux Yea, I looked into the transform property and tried. It was messing it up

Answer (score 0):

When you scale something the origin of the scaling is 0,0 if nothing else is defined (in CSS you have the property [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)). So, to keep things simple you place all shapes around 0,0. If you look at the path element for the line, the scaling origin is 0,0, and the line starts in 100,0. When scaled the distance will be larger and the line longer. This is also useful then I rotate all the use elements -- they also rotate around 0,0 -- and they all form the circle around the face. I also moved the face so that the upper left corner of the face icon is in 0,0 (ok, so here, the center is not 0,0!), but I fix that, because I know that the width and height of the face icon is 49.5,49.5, so I translate in negative direction (-24.75,-24.75).
Using a `<g>` element I can now move everything into the center of the SVG.

The scaling is done on another `<g>` element (with the class name `scale`), scaling all elements using CSS (well, you don't explain how you are going to scale the SVG, but set the transform attribute on the `<g>` element instead of the class attribute).

I removed the white circle and the clip-path. I couldn't see the point -- maybe you can explain the idea?

### Update

Use the stroke-dasharray on each line to extend it. I don't know how the logic should be, so here I just extend the lines if the value of the range is less than the index of the `<use>` elements.

```js
const useElms = document.querySelectorAll('svg use');
document.forms.form01.num.addEventListener('change', e => {
  [...useElms].forEach((elm, i) => {
    let offset = (i <= parseInt(e.target.value)) ? 0 : 4;
    elm.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', offset);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

use {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="229" height="229" viewBox="0 0 270 270" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M 100 0 h 35" pathLength="10" stroke-dasharray="10" />
  </defs>
<g transform="translate(135 135)">
  <g stroke="#737A91" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round">
  <path transform="translate(-24.75 -24.75)" d="M 13.75 0 H 13.2 C 8.5796 0 6.2694 0 4.5046 0.8992 C 2.9522 1.6902 1.6902 2.9522 0.8992 4.5046 C 0 6.2694 0 8.5796 0 13.2 V 13.75 M 13.75 49.5 H 13.2 C 8.5796 49.5 6.2694 49.5 4.5046 48.601 C 2.9522 47.81 1.6902 46.548 0.8992 44.995 C 0 43.231 0 40.92 0 36.3 V 35.75 M 49.5 13.75 V 13.2 C 49.5 8.5796 49.5 6.2694 48.601 4.5046 C 47.81 2.9522 46.548 1.6902 44.995 0.8992 C 43.231 0 40.92 0 36.3 0 H 35.75 M 49.5 35.75 V 36.3 C 49.5 40.92 49.5 43.231 48.601 44.995 C 47.81 46.548 46.548 47.81 44.995 48.601 C 43.231 49.5 40.92 49.5 36.3 49.5 H 35.75 M 12.375 13.75 V 17.875 M 37.125 13.75 V 17.875 M 22 26.4 C 24.2 26.4 26.125 24.475 26.125 22.275 V 13.75 M 33.551 33.55 C 28.601 38.5 20.626 38.5 15.676 33.55" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(0)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(8)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(16)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(24)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(32)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(40)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(48)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(56)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(64)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(72)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(80)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(88)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(96)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(104)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(112)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(120)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(128)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(136)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(144)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(152)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(160)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(168)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(176)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(184)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(192)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(200)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(208)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(216)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(224)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(232)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(240)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(248)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(256)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(264)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(272)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(280)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(288)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(296)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(304)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(312)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(320)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(328)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(336)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(344)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
    <use href="#p1" transform="rotate(352)" stroke-dashoffset="4" />
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
<form name="form01"><input type="range" name="num" min="-1" max="45" value="-1" step="1"></form>
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well. Here's a Youtube video link explaining how the lines should scale/increase in height.

https://youtube.com/shorts/seNmA_mTjxA?si=WgzYlqbpHk3WI5at